Gitbook link to a tab
I'm trying to get a link to a specific tab, added in a gitbook page. There are three tabs and I want a link to the second one (when the link is accessed, the page should be displayed, with the second tab opened). But the page is always opened with the first tab displayed. There is also a heading in the second tab, but adding it to the link doesn't work too, the first tab is always displayed.
Any ideas?
